# Tomcat not reusing hanging postgres process

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat

I have an issue where basic queries from tomcat app is causing all postgres process to go into "idle in transaction" state.

This is because for some reasons, the queries never gets completed. Relates to application issue and raised issue with developer of the app and they are taking a look.

As tomcat thinks the query is still active, it never does a rollback or commit and hangs.

I am able to kill the "idle in transaction" processes, but tomcat does not automatically clear abandon connections and start new one without having to restart tomcat.

Is there a way to force tomcat to clear the abandoned connection?

```
 labkey                    |  8195 | 2018-04-17 10:53:17.002785+01 |                        | idle in transaction
 labkey                    |  8359 | 2018-04-17 10:53:16.632977+01 |                        | idle in transaction
 labkey                    |  8249 | 2018-04-17 10:53:16.631433+01 |                        | idle in transaction
 labkey                    |  8250 | 2018-04-17 10:53:17.173161+01 |                        | idle in transaction
 labkey                    |  8251 | 2018-04-17 10:53:16.194544+01 |                        | idle in transaction
 labkey                    |  8358 | 2018-04-17 10:53:16.634106+01 |                        | idle in transaction
 labkey                    |  8362 | 2018-04-17 10:53:14.843128+01 |                        | idle in transaction
 labkey                    |  8382 | 2018-04-17 10:53:15.903067+01 |                        | idle in transaction
```

Comment: What do you mean with "reuse the process"? If you kill a connection there is nothing to "reuse" after that.

Comment: Maybe the word reuse is the wrong one. But forcing tomcat to clear abandon connections and start new one without having to restart tomcat. Thanks

Comment: Tomcat will never issue a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`. That's up to the application. Drivers in JDBC-compliant mode will issue a `COMMIT` when resetting themselves into `auto-commit` mode, assuming that your connection-pool is configured to hand-out connections in `auto-commit` more.

Comment: What is your definition of "abandoned"? Applications usually use a connection-pool which intentionally maintains connections to the database to avoid the overhead of creating a new physical connection for each connection required by the application. This is generally seen as a performance optimization.